# Regex from python list

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Today, I found out that regex `r"['a', 'b']"` matches `'a, b'`.

Why is that? What does comma and ' mean inside `[]`?

Thank you.

Comment: Can we see the implementation of the regex?

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html ?

Comment: `['a', 'b']` is the same as `[',ab]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[]` is used to define character sets in regular expressions.  The expression will match if the string contains any of the characters in that set.

Your regular expression:

```
 r"['a', 'b']"
```

Says "match if string contains `'` or `a` or `,` or `b`.  As @Patrick Haugh mentions in his comment.  Your expression is equivalent to `[',ab]`.  Repeating the same character in the set does nothing.

http://www.regexpal.com/ is a great site for testing your regular expressions.  It can help break it down for you and explain what your expression does and why it matches on certain strings.